# dotnet core 3.1 angular identity server 4 views

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I was playing with a new project using dotnet core 3.1, angular and individual user accounts.

After create the project I added scaffolded items for Identity.

All views are using MVC.

Is there Angular views version for this?

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: @RomanMarusyk, so how people are doing that?

Comment: create their own views

Answer (score 0):

When we are using IdentityServer as an identity provider. We are using different approach as *Individual User Accounts*. So, identity provider service will handle all operations such as create, update, change password, etc.

This is the reason of why we don't have same things in Angular and IdentityServer. But you can use [Skoruba](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin) project, which handle a lot of requirements.